# How to get port infomation about tcp connection in linux kernel?

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel

I'm writing a kernel module and I need to know which port the tcp sock is sent out. The 'port' here means WLAN port， 4g port or IP port.

I've been looking for port information in the kernel source code tcp.h (struct tcp_sock), sock.h (struct sock) and some other struct that relate to sock for days, but I found nothing. There are some variables look like port information but not.

Did I just go the wrong way? How can I get that information in kernel?

My kernel is [linux-mptcp](https://github.com/multipath-tcp/mptcp), just linux 414 with some multipath-tcp code in it.

Comment: Are you talking about Physical interface or tcp port ?.

Comment: I'm not sure, I can't tell the deference between Physical interface and tcp port. I want to know as they are all named as 'port', are there any association between them? Like, port 123456 is WLAN port, or port 555555 is 4g port? @Sasi

Comment: Can you point the source code you are referring too.

Comment: linux/include/net/tcp.h and linux/include/net/sock.h. I'm looking for the variables. It looks like I'v found the answer. The answer is we don't need to tell WLAN port, 4g port or IP port in linux kernel, because that's physical layer's work, while linux kernel serves upon the transport layer. But this question can still be here just as a hack question ... just for fun.